# Select from table echoes one instead of more rows

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am facing a problem and I would like your help!

**I have built this:**

```
$stmt_select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE `user_id`=$id;");
$stmt_select->execute();

while ($row_select = $stmt_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo  '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <strong>'. $row_select['area_store'] .'</strong>
                            <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><i>'. $row_select['name_store'] .'</i></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>';        
};
```

I have two rows into the table but `echo` displays only one result.Any ideas?

Comment: `print_r($row_select);` and posts its value

Comment: Yes, it displays two rows..

Comment: May be problem occur due to your UI or css

Comment: Ok!I'll check it..If notice anything wrong please let me know.

Comment: The problem was this `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">`....`</ul>`.It should be outside the while..loop

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
$stmt_select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE `user_id`=$id;");
$stmt_select->execute();

$res = $stmt_select->get_result();

while ($row_select = $res->fetch_assoc()) {


          echo  '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                 <li>
                 <a href="#">
                 <div>
                 <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <strong>'. $row_select['area_store'] .'</strong>
                 <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><i>'. $row_select['name_store'] .'</i></span>
                </div>
               </a>
              </li>
            </ul>';        
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fetchAll the data and than do a foreach loop like so

```
$stmt_select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE `user_id`=$id;");
$stmt_select->execute();
$stmt_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($stmt_select as $row) {
    echo  '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <strong>'. $row['area_store'] .'</strong>
                            <span class="pull-right text-muted small"><i>'. $row['name_store'] .'</i></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>';  
}
```

also i would suggest you to escape your variables before entering the sql query.

```
$stmt_select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `stores` WHERE `user_id`= :id");
$stmt_select->execute(["id" => $id]);
$stmt_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help solve ur probem

```
  $stmt =$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM stores where user_id=:user_id")  
  $stmt->bindValue(":user_id", $id);
  $stmt->execute();

  $results=$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(count($results) > 0 ){

    foreach ($row as $results) {

        echo  "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts\">
                <li>
                    <a href=\"#\">
                        <div>
                            <i class=\"fa fa-home\"></i> <strong>".$row['area_store'] ."</strong>
                            <span class=\"pull-right text-muted small\"><i>".$row['name_store'] ."</i></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>";  

    }
  }elseif (count($results) <= 0) {
     echo "no records found";
  }
```

if you found this helpful please mark the answer :)